# forwarding eMails from exchange misses sender address

Tags: exchange, smtp

when forwarding eMails from Exchange to Icewarp, there is nop sender address displayed in icewarp.

Even in the code of the eMail there is a from-address, there is no from address shown in smtp  log.
And the  from-address in email-source shows two dashes as visible name like "--user@dom.com

see:
smtp-log: 13:52:04 <<< MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=4130 BODY=7BIT

eMail-source: From: - - myuser@somedom.com

in the end the eMails show iup in the Inbox coming from "--" which kills all sorting. Even the sender address is then showed in the eMail-Windo anyway.

Someone knows how to push Exchange to send the FROM with smtp?

INFO: The same happened if i create a transport rule :-(

Comment: Here is a thread which seems to be post by you:**[Forwarding eMails from Exchange to Icewarp bounces back, but not via distribution list](https://serverfault.com/questions/1026375/forwarding-emails-from-exchange-to-icewarp-bounces-back-but-not-via-distributio/1026512#1026512)**, and you could refer to my reply behind.

Comment: Yes, also from me. I thought the first question (the other thread you linked) reads too complicate that i thought about splitting up my problems into smaller parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command to trace the forward emails(**[Message Tracking Log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2019)**), maybe it could help you find the reason why the SMTP sender missed:

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Sender <Sender's email address> -Recipients <Email address from icewarp server> -MessageSubject "<Subject>" -Start "<Start Date and Time>" -End "<End Date and Time>
```

[image]